# Can `merge!` change a CONST in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, constants

I have a situation where `merge!` seems to modify the value of a CONST.  Can this occur?  How?

I'm doing some API ingestion and mapping, *like you do*...

```
module Placement  
  FEATURE_DEFAULTS = {
    "thingone" => "false",
    "thingtwo" => "false"
  }

  def extract_features!(feat)
    feat['norm_features'] ||= FEATURE_DEFAULTS
    feat['norm_features'].merge!(
      Array(feat['attributes']['feature']).reduce({}) do |h,f|
        h[f] = "true"
        h
      end
    )
  end

  def get_placement(_opts)
    data_source["things"]["thing"].map do |thing|
      product = {}
      thing.each do |key, value|
        new_key = RENAME_FIELDS[key] || key
        new_value = REPLACE_FIELDS[key] || value
        product[new_key] = new_value
      end

      binding.pry  # 1
      extract_features!(product)
      binding.pry  # 2
      product
    end
  end
end
```

Later, I include this in a class for the API client, and then I call the `get_placement` method.

### Dilemma

#### step 1

For the first run, in pry binding 1 & 2, the value of `FEATURE_DEFAULTS` is as seen above.  For 2 the value of `FEATURE_DEFAULTS` is the same, and the value of `product['norm_features']` is the same (plus the results of the meshing operation of `extract_features!`

#### step 2

The output (to the `caller` of `get_placement`), for every `thing`/product, is

```
  FEATURE_DEFAULTS = {
    "thingone" => true,
    "thingtwo" => true
  }
```

#### step 3

When I run this the second time (after starting up the service / app), the value of `FEATURE_DEFAULTS`, and pry binding 1 & 2, is

```
  FEATURE_DEFAULTS = {
    "thingone" => true,
    "thingtwo" => true
  }
```

What is happening here?

> This seems to confirm that, after running the `extract_features!` method, the `FEATURE_DEFAULTS` CONST is changed.  If I do not use `merge!` in `extract_features!`, and use `merge` instead, then the CONST value does not change.

I can post more code, if needed, or most to a Gist.
Ruby MRI 2.2.2

I am doing this inside a rails app, but I don't see that it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a situation where `merge!` seems to modify the value of a CONST. Can this occur? How?

No, in general, methods cannot change variable bindings, regardless of whether those variables are local variables, instance variables, class variables, global variables, or constants. Variables aren't objects in Ruby, you can't call methods on them, you can't pass them as arguments to methods, ergo, you can't tell them to change themselves.

The exception to this are meta-programming methods like [`Binding#local_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set), [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set), [`Module#class_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_set), or [`Module#const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-const_set).

What you *can* do, however, and what you *are* doing in this case, is tell the object the variable *points to* to change itself. The documentation for [`Hash#merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) is unfortunately a bit unclear in that it does not *explicitly* mention that `Hash#merge!` mutates its receiver.

> This seems to confirm that, after running the `extract_features!` method, the `FEATURE_DEFAULTS` CONST is changed.  If I do not use `merge!` in `extract_features!`, and use `merge` instead, then the CONST value does not change.

No, it only confirms that the state of the object `FEATURE_DEFAULTS` *points to* changed, it doesn't say anything about whether the binding of `FEATURE_DEFAULTS`, i.e. *which* object it points to, changed. You can confirm that the constant still points to the same object by looking at its `object_id`.

Of course, constants can be re-assigned anyway, albeit triggering a warning.

Comment: I expected `merge!` to mutate its receiver - that was the intention.  I didn't expect it to mutate the value of `FEATURE_DEFAULTS`.  I get what you're saying; that `FEATURE_DEFAULTS` points to an object (`object_id` doesn't change), and that object's value was modified.  Still feels like 'changing a constant', but I hear what you're saying.

Comment: The definition of "constant" in Ruby is "generates a warning if re-assigned". And that definition isn't violated by the object the constant points to being mutable. Note that it is a fundamental pillar of OO, that you cannot know how an object is implemented inside, which means you cannot know whether a method may or may not mutate its receiver, which means that something like "deep-constness" simply cannot exist because there is no way to know which methods you would be allowed to call and which not.